# LC-3 Operands that only use registers

Tags: lc3

Hi i had a quick question

Which of the following LC-3 instructions can only have operands that are in registers (i.e. cannot have
immediate or memory operands)?

a. ADD b. NOT c. LD d. AND

From what I can tell this would be NOT as ADD and AND use registers along with immediate values. While LD has the pcoffset? So I was wondering if this is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look up the NOT instruction for LC-3, you'll see that the opcode takes the format:

```
opcode   destination-reg   source-reg
 1001       xxx                yyy      111111
```

or:

```
1001xxxyyy111111
```

ADD takes the form:

```
0001xxxyyy000zzz for register values
0001xxxyyy1zzzzz for immediate values
```

AND takes the form:

```
0101xxxyyy000zzz for register values
0101xxxyyy1zzzzz for immediate values
```

LD takes a register to load into and an offset to the memory:

```
0010xxxyyyyyyyyy
```

If you count the offset as an operand, then the answer is NOT and LD, otherwise, it's just NOT.